# How can anonymous class method parameters be returned to the original instantiating class?

Tags: java, class, anonymous-class

Here's my code:

```
public void pollLocation()
{
    myLocation.getLocation(this, new LocationResult()
    {
        public void gotLocation(Location location)
        {
            //I want to assign Location object from here...
        }
    });
}

private Location lastLocation; //...to here.
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `lastLocation = something` does not work?

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me that `gotLocation` is an asynchronous callback, but that you're expecting it to run synchronously.

Comment: @Bruno: Wrong.  Inner classes can write to all fields (as opposed to locals).  They get a reference to the parent's `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Generally you can just write

```
lastLocation = location
```

But maybe the LocationResult class/interface also has a field named lastLocation. In this case you have to write

```
OuterClassName.this.lastLocation = location
```

But since it looks like you would do some asynchronous polling, it's too dangerous to do this without synchronization. Also you wouldn't notice when the lastLocation gets set. So it's better to use a synchronized setter in the outer class.

Comment: Note that the use of a synchronized setter will only guarantee thread safety if every read of the variable (even inside the instance itself) is done through a synchronized getter (that acquires the same lock as the setter -- which is the case for `synchronized void setX(x) {...}` / `synchronized X getX() {...}`).

Comment: Yes I didn't understand that the anonymous class was in its instantiating class's scope. I'm going to use Synchronized getters and setters too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a setter:

```
public void pollLocation()
{
    myLocation.getLocation(this, new LocationResult()
    {
        public void gotLocation(Location location)
        {
            //I want to assign Location object from here...
            setLastLocation(...);
        }
    });
}

private Location lastLocation; //...to here.
private void setLastLocation(Location l) { lastLocation = l; }
```

Just be careful about multithreading issues. If you are using multiple threads, you'd better declare lastLocation `volatile` or use an `AtomicReference`. Otherwise, your code might not work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Make lastLocation a final [java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) and set it to your heart's content.

(Edit: you sure a simple assignment doesn't work? It looks like that works in Eclipse ...)